# Image resize script - multiple sources

Tags: php, image, get, resize

New here and pretty new to writing php scripts etc.

I have a few weather IP cameras which produce high resolution (3MP) images and I have come up with the below script so far to reduce the size of the images and also to select which camera to select via c= "last ip octet". Also some of the cameras are from different manufacture so path to the image.jpg will be different.
An example is http://www.example.com/WeatherCam.php?c=2&w=800&h=600 in which it will pull the image from http://10.x.x.2/image.jpg (Camera 2) then reduce it to 800x600 pixels.

```
<?php  
// Get Camera Number
 if(isset($_GET['c'])){
  $num=$_GET['c'];
}

// The image from camera
$filename = "http://10.99.99.".$num."/image.jpg"; 

// Set a maximum height and width  
$width = 2048;  
$height = 1536;  

 if(isset($_GET['w'])){
  $width=$_GET['w'];
}
 if(isset($_GET['h'])){
   $height=$_GET['h'];
}

// Set Content type to jpeg 
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');  

list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);  
$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;  

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {  
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;  
} else {  
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;  
}  

// Create new images  
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$sourceimage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);  
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $sourceimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);  

// Output Images & Cleanup
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
imagedestroy($sourceimage);
imagedestroy($image_p);
?>
```

Could you please help me out so I can use a array or similar to select which camera to use instead of the crude way I’m doing it below?
I’m thinking somewhere along the lines of:

```
array(
  'id' => array(
    1 => http://10.x.x.1/image.jpg,
    2 => http://10.x.x.2/image.jpg,
    3 => http://10.x.x.3/jpg/image.jpg
  )
```

This is mainly so I can have full control over which cameras I would like to be accessible from the php script and not to select any other ip camera on the same subnet.

I would like it so if the id is not specified in the URL it will default to either to camera 1 or another image i.e. imagenotfound.jpg.

**EDIT:**
Below is new code I have come up with, any issues anyone can see? So far it seems to be working well.

```
<?php  
// Get Filename from URL  
if (isset($_GET['ID']) AND $_GET['ID'] == 'null') {
    $filename = 'no-image.jpg';
}
switch ((isset($_GET['ID']) ? $_GET['ID'] : '')) {
    case '1':
        $filename = "http://10.x.x.1/jpg/image.jpg";
        break;
    case '2':
        $filename = "http://10.x.x.2/jpg/image.jpg";
        break;
    case '3':
        $filename = "http://10.x.x.1/image.jpg";
        break;
    default:
        $filename = 'no-image.jpg';
        break;
}

// Get Image Quality from URL  
if (isset($_GET['q']) AND $_GET['q'] == 'null') {
    $quality = '100';
}
switch ((isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '')) {
    case '1':
        $quality = "100";
        break;
    case '2':
        $quality = "80";
        break;
    case '3':
        $quality = "75";
        break;
    default:
        $quality = '100';
        break;
}

// Get Image Width & Height from URL  
if (isset($_GET['s']) AND $_GET['s'] == 'null') {
        $width = "800";
        $height = "600";
}
switch ((isset($_GET['s']) ? $_GET['s'] : '')) {
    case '1':
        $width = "800";
        $height = "600";
        break;
    case '2':
        $width = "1024";
        $height = "768";
        break;
    case '3':
        $width = "704";
        $height = "576";
        break;
    case '4':
        $width = "2048";
        $height = "1536";
        break;
    default:
        $width = "800";
        $height = "600";
        break;
}

// Content type  
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');  

// Get new dimensions  
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);  

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;  

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {  
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;  
} else {  
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;  
}  

// Resample  
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$sourceimage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);  
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $sourceimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);  

// Output  
imagejpeg($image_p, null, $quality);
imagedestroy($sourceimage);
imagedestroy($image_p);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally write the following snippet:

```
// Get Image Quality from URL  
if (isset($_GET['q']) AND $_GET['q'] == 'null') {
    $quality = '100';
}
switch ((isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '')) {
    case '1':
        $quality = "100";
        break;
    case '2':
        $quality = "80";
        break;
    case '3':
        $quality = "75";
        break;
    default:
        $quality = '100';
        break;
}
```

in this way:

```
$quality_list = array(
    1 => 100,
    2 => 80,
    3 => 75
);

$quality = (isset($_GET['q']) && isset($quality_list[$_GET['q']]))  
       ? $quality_list[$_GET['q']]
       : 100;  // default quality
```

However, it is just a matter of preferences.